# JavaFX KEY_TYPED events are doing nothing

Tags: java, javafx, keyboard, keyboard-events, keyboard-input

I'm making a video game with a simple inventory system.  I'm trying to make it so that whenever you press the "Z" key it would show or hide the inventory GUI.  I don't know why, but the KEY_TYPED key events aren't working.  The KEY_PRESSED and KEY_RELEASED key events are working perfectly fine.

Here is my key event handler class:

```
public static KeyCode handle(javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getEventType() == javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED) {
        e.consume();
        return e.getCode();
    }

    if (e.getEventType() == javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED) {
        e.consume();
        return e.getCode();
    }

    if (e.getEventType() == javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED) {
        e.consume();
        return e.getCode();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Here is where I'm using the key events:

```
    primaryStage.getScene().setOnKeyTyped(event -> {
        KeyCode e = KeyEvent.handle(event);

        if (e == KeyCode.Z) {
            System.out.println("test");
        }
    });
```

When I tried pressing the key, it did absolutely nothing.

Comment: Use `KEY_TYPED` events when the user is typing into some kind of text input control. If you need to do an action based on a key, use `KEY_PRESSED`. Also, I'm not understanding the purpose of your `handle(KeyEvent)` method.

Comment: A key-typed event is the result of one or more key-pressed and/or key-released events.  If you consume those, you are probably preventing key-typed events from occurring.  Is there any actual benefit to consuming the key events?  (Also, naming your own class `KeyEvent` seems like a bad idea that will lead to confusion.  Perhaps `KeyEventHandler` would be better?)

Comment: Oh I thought that `KEY_TYPED` was the result of when someone presses and released a key.  I guess I should use `KEY_RELEASED` right?

Answer (score 3):

On a KEY_TYPED event you extract the *code* from the event and return it from your handler, and later compare it to `KeyCode.Z`.

The [API Doc for KeyEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html) states:

> For key pressed and key released events, the code variable contains the event's key code. For key typed events, the code variable always contains KeyCode.UNDEFINED.

So you are comparing `KeyCode.UNDEFINED` to `KeyCode.Z` which will not match.

You will have to use `KeyEvent.getCharacter()` in case of a key typed event and compare that to `"Z"`

Comment: Could you give me an example, because it still isn't working for me?